# Get subquery list from XML c#

Tags: c#, xml, lambda, subquery

I am writing a code that reads from XML and put the information on the list. 
the information:

1. Employee Name
2. the months he already finish
3. the months he needs to work on.

and they are all exist in XML File.

I wrote this code :

```
List<MonthlyInformation> result =
                doc.Root.Elements().Descendants(nsXml + "MitarbeiterGroup")
                .Select(x => new MonthlyInformation
                {
                    Firstname = (string)x.Attribute("Group9"),
                    FinishedMonths = x.Descendants("Monat3").Select(s => new FinishedMonth {MonthName = (string)s.Attribute("Monat3"), Money = (string)s.Element("Cell").Attribute("Textbox142") }).ToList(),
                    ForecastMonths = x.Descendants("Monat9").Select(s => new ForecastMonth { MonthName = (string)s.Attribute("Monat9"), Money = (string)s.Element("Cell").Attribute("Textbox143") }).ToList()
                }).ToList();
```

the code works fine but both the FinishedMonths and ForecastMonths datamember are always empty.

here is a part of the XML

```
<MitarbeiterGroup Group9="Name....">
            <Textbox111>
              <UmsatzInternGroup_Collection>
                <UmsatzInternGroup>
                  <Monat3 Monat3="Jan.">
                    <Cell Textbox142="11325" />
                  </Monat3>
                </UmsatzInternGroup>
                <UmsatzInternGroup>
                  <Monat3 Monat3="Feb.">
                    <Cell Textbox142="12345" />
                  </Monat3>
                </UmsatzInternGroup>
              </UmsatzInternGroup_Collection>
               <ForecastExternGroup_Collection>
                <ForecastExternGroup>
                  <Monat9 Monat9="Sep.">
                    <Cell Textbox143="17130" />
                  </Monat9>
                </ForecastExternGroup>
                <ForecastExternGroup>
                  <Monat9 Monat9="Okt.">
                    <Cell Textbox143="18000" />
                  </Monat9>
                </ForecastExternGroup>
              </ForecastExternGroup_Collection>
            </Textbox111>
      </MitarbeiterGroup>
```

so I need to get for every employee all the months in "Monat3" and all the forecast Months in "Monat9".

please if you can help as soon as possible

Comment: One thing to note is that for Monat3 you're using attribute Textbox143 and for Monat9 your also using Textbox143. Monat3 attribute is actually Textbox142.

Comment: correct I copy it by mistake but still do not work.

Comment: Add the namespace to x.Descendants("Monat3").

Comment: did not work, instead it gave me an error of reading the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your `nsXml` variable looks like, however changing this line
`doc.Root.Elements().Descendants(nsXml + "MitarbeiterGroup")`
to
`doc.Root.Elements()`

worked for me. 
[image]

Maybe you have the ns incorrect?

EDIT:

This is the XML I used

```
<MitarbeiterGroup Group9="Name....">
    <Textbox111>
        <UmsatzInternGroup_Collection>
            <UmsatzInternGroup>
                <Monat3 Monat3="Jan.">
                    <Cell Textbox142="11325" />
                </Monat3>
            </UmsatzInternGroup>
            <UmsatzInternGroup>
                <Monat3 Monat3="Feb.">
                    <Cell Textbox142="12345" />
                </Monat3>
                <ForecastExternGroup_Collection>
                    <ForecastExternGroup>
                        <Monat9 Monat9="Sep.">
                            <Cell Textbox143="17130" />
                        </Monat9>
                    </ForecastExternGroup>
                    <ForecastExternGroup>
                        <Monat9 Monat9="Okt.">
                            <Cell Textbox143="18000" />
                        </Monat9>
                    </ForecastExternGroup>
                </ForecastExternGroup_Collection>
            </UmsatzInternGroup>
        </UmsatzInternGroup_Collection>
    </Textbox111>
</MitarbeiterGroup>
```

EDIT:

use `doc.Descendants("MitarbeiterGroup")` instead of `doc.Root.Elements().Descendants()`

I beleive this has something to do with the way Elements() works. If you compare the following two:

```
var descendants = doc.Descendants().ToList();
var elements = doc.Elements().ToList();
```

You can see that `Descendants()` is a flat list of all the children where as `Elements()` is tree like hierarchy, and even though you are calling `Descendants()` you've already called `Elements()`

EDIT:

Inside the lambda where you again call `x.Descendants()`, instead of using calling it like `x.Descendants("Monat3")` or `x.Descendants(XName.Get("Monat3"))` it needs to be fully qualified *(? not sure on the terminology)*, it should look like `x.Descendants(XName.Get("Monat3", ns))`

```
string testURL = "XML.xml";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(testURL);
string ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace().ToString();
List<MonthlyInformation> result =
doc.Descendants(XName.Get("MitarbeiterGroup", ns))
.Select(x =>
new MonthlyInformation
{
    Name = (string)x.Attribute("Group9"),
    FinishedMonths = x.Descendants(XName.Get("Monat3", ns)).Select(s => new FinishedMonth
    {
        MonthName = (string)s.Attribute("Monat3"),
        Money = "money" //(string)s.Element("Cell").Attribute("Textbox142") 
    }).ToList(),
    ForecastMonths = x.Descendants(XName.Get("Monat9", ns)).Select(s => new ForecastMonth
    {
        MonthName = (string)s.Attribute("Monat9"),
        Money = "money" //(string)s.Element("Cell").Attribute("Textbox143")
    }).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

Comment: it gave me an empty string

Comment: and the name space is correct because I am reading it from the xml itself, beside it gave me a list of the names.
XElement report = (XElement)doc.FirstNode;
                XNamespace nsXml = report.GetDefaultNamespace();

Comment: I've added the XML I used to test

Comment: wait there is misundertanding, the UmsatzInternGroup is a sibling with ForecastExternGroup not a parent

Comment: Can you add a full example, please.

Comment: check the edit. it is hard to give the whole XML. it is very big contain more than 100 thousand line. but this is a correct part.

Comment: Edited my original answer.

Comment: I still receive an empty lists for both Months list

Comment: himmm, I am not that strong with XML, I understand your point. but how can we figure the answer?

Comment: See this example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5oherisywbfpuqy/ConsoleApplication25.zip?dl=1

Comment: I cannot load the project. it gave me an error when I opened it

Comment: It is VS2015 .NET 4.5.2

Comment: the same result. the counts of the two lists still 0

Comment: Have you tried something like `doc.XPathSelectElements("//Monat3").ToList()`? Does it return something?